# How do I use the cv::dct function in this context?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to implement the discrete cosinus transform function as part of an assignment.

To check that my function is working correctly, I would like to call the `cv::dct` function on my arguments and see if I got the same result with my own function.

I got this vector:

```
std::vector<cv::Mat_<uchar>> vBlocks;
```

which is a vector containing matrix of (8*8) size. I call my function like this:

```
for(size_t b=0; b<vBlocks.size(); ++b) {
    vDCTBlocks[b] = dct(vBlocks[b]); // here dct is the function I coded myself
}
```

However, how would I call the `cv::dct` function to check that the results are the same?
I tried:

```
for(size_t b=0; b<vBlocks.size(); ++b) {
    cv::dct(vBlocks[b], vBlocks[b]);
}
```

but im getting the following error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (type == CV_32FC1 || type == CV_64FC1)
>   in cv::dct, file E:\pistc\open cv\modules\core\src\dxt.cpp, line 3603
>   Caught cv::Exceptions: E:\pistc\opencv\modules\core\src\dxt.cpp:3603:
>   error: (-215) type == CV_32FC1  || type == CV_64FC1 in function
>   cv::dct

I would guess that this is due to the fact that I'm using matrix and not arrays for the arguments of `cv::dct`, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Seems rather a difference in the expected types. [CV_32FC1](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37530646/edit) means '32bit float on a single channel' and you are providing something originated from a `cv::Mat_<uchar>`

Comment: You have to convert `Mat_<uchar>` to `Mat_<double>` or `Mat_<float>`. For example, like `Mat block = Mat_<double>(vBlocks[b])`.

Comment: Ah I see thanks. I'll try that.